# ESLint в Vs-code ругается

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

```
[Info  - 11:51:00 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 11:51:05 AM] ESLint library loaded from:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Warn  - 11:51:05 AM] No ESLint configuration (e.g .eslintrc) found for file: d:\Project Web\JS\Learning JS\task.js
File will not be validated. Consider running 'eslint --init' in the workspace folder Learning JS
Alternatively you can disable ESLint by executing the 'Disable ESLint' command.
```

Не совсем понимаю что он хочет. Насколько понимаю чего-то в папке моего проекта?

Comment: Файл конфигурации .eslintrc?

Comment: Даже не знаю...